# SWT Grid Layout width

Tags: java, swt

I'm trying to create a simple display using SWT. So far, I am successfully displaying information from my database and displaying it using a RowLayout, with each row containing a GridLayout. It looks like this:

[image]

What I really want is for the rows to extend to take up the full width of the window. How do I achieve this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual way to achieve this is to use [`GridData`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html). This `GridData` tells the component how to behave within it's parent, e.g. how to spread across the parent.

By using:

```
component.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));
```

you tell the component to occupy as much space as possible horizontally, but only the necessary space vertically.

Here is a small example that should behave in the way you expect it to:

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Display display = Display.getDefault();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);

        /* GridLayout for the Shell to make things easier */
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            createRow(shell, i);
        }

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed())
        {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void createRow(Shell shell, int i)
    {
        /* GridLayout for the rows, two columns, equal column width */
        Composite row = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        row.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, true));

        /* Make each row expand horizontally but not vertically */
        row.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));

        /* Create the content of the row, expand horizontally as well */
        Button first = new Button(row, SWT.PUSH);
        first.setText("FIRST " + i);
        first.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));
        Button second = new Button(row, SWT.PUSH);
        second.setText("SECOND " + i);
        second.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING, true, false));
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like after startup:

[image]

and after resizing:

[image]

---

As a side note: I would suggest reading [this](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) tutorial from Eclipse about Layouts, if you haven't already read it. Every SWT developer should have read it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How can I get the same functionality but with columns of different sizes?

Comment: I used nested gridlayouts to approximate the look I was going for. Thanks again.